# How to get selectedIndex value on chage and append in other text box value in angular 7

Tags: angular

In my angular app i have a form and there are four fields in the form when i change food item from drop down then price field not change regarding to that food any body have idea.

this is the response of api[image]

it shows an error like ERROR `TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined`

this is my component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Foot Item :</label>
        <select name="item_id" #item_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="formData.item_id" class="form-control" (change)="updatePrice($event.target)">
            <option value="0">--Select--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of itemList.data" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.item_name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

This is .ts file

```
updatePrice(ctrl){
    if(ctrl.selectedIndex == 0)
          {
              this.formData.price = 0;
              this.formData.item_name = '';
          }
          else
          {
               this.formData.price = this.itemList[ctrl.selectedIndex-1].price;
      this.formData.item_name = this.itemList[ctrl.selectedIndex-1].item_name;
          }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work for you:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Foot Item :</label>
       <select name="item_id" #item_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="formData.item_id" 
          class="form-control" (change)="updatePrice($event)">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option *ngFor="let item of itemList.data;let i=index" [value]="i"> 
          {{item.item_name}}</option>
       </select>
  </div>
```

and in "ts" file:

```
 updatePrice(ctrl){
    if(ctrl.target.value == -1)
    {
        this.formData.price = 0;
        this.formData.item_name = '';
    }
    else
    {

    this.formData.price = this.itemList.data[ctrl.target.value].price;
    this.formData.item_name = this.itemList.data[ctrl.target.value].item_name;
    }

}
```

Comment: in which line are you getting this error? 
this.formData.price or   this.itemList[ctrl.target.value].price?

Comment: may I see your itemList json?

Comment: this.formData.price = this.itemList[ctrl.selectedIndex-1].price;  and price is undefine

Comment: I think the "data" was missing after "this.itemList", I have edited my answer it should work now

Comment: @MohammadrezaImani, your check it's wrong, must be if (ctrl.target.value== **-1** ). And take account that formData.item_id becomes the value of the index, not the id

Comment: how to pass the data after this.itemlist

Comment: yes, I edited my answer. now you can use my code I think.

Comment: what kind of error?  syntax or runtime? if your json is what you show me it must work with this.itemList.data. 
this.itemList["data"][ctrl.target.value].price;
but I think you should use type "any" for itemList

like this:

itemList : any; and then assign data to it;

Comment: this works for me this.itemList["data"][ctrl.selectedIndex-1].price thank a lot

Comment: your welcome. if you don't mind giving me the points of this answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is that you are doing this.itemList[index].price while in DOM you've iterated itemList.data. So it should be itemList.data[index].price.

Replacing change listener for ngModelChange will emit the value of the selected option. Since value of option is index when change option is selected index of the selected option will be emitted and you will be able to access array item easily.